# Go requirements.txt for Dockerfile

Tags: go, dependencies, dockerfile

I need to write a Dockerfile to my project that needs lots of `go get`s to external packages.
Is there any way to get a list of external packages to import? 
I want to know every external package that I need to put in Dockerfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the project [`cespare/deplist`](https://github.com/cespare/deplist)

Or check [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/611QEJqkDKw) which uses [`go list`](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-List_packages).

```
go list -f '{{.ImportPath}}' P/... | xargs -n 1 deplist | grep -v P | sort -u
```

> with `P` being the partial package path.

Comment: But it only prints out the internal packages that I just defined. Can I only print out external package? I ran `go list ./...` but only get my packages. But I want to print out like `github.com/golang/glog` if one of my package uses this package.

Comment: @cvxv31431asdas I think that what deplist does.